# Calling an executable with parameters in ExtendScript

Tags: javascript, command-line, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

My Illustrator ExtendScript produces some XML files and I need to call an executable file WITH these files as parameters at the end of Main(). The solutions I've found have been disappointing at best.

Currently my solution without parameters is just

```
if (confirm("Would you like to open the NineGridViewer utility?", false)) {
    // Temporary: prompt user to manually find path to executable
    File.openDialog( 'Select path for NineGridViewer utility executable file.', '*.exe' ).execute();
}
```

I understand that I could produce a file which contains the .\executable [params] that I want and call that file as an executable. But I'd really like a nicer solution if possible.

**Edit:** [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920592/adobe-after-effects-extend-script-how-to-run-script-from-command-line-and-pass) and page 180 of [this documentation](http://blogs.adobe.com/aftereffects/files/2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf?file=2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf) reference a system class with convenient methods that do exactly what I need. But the interpreter seems to have no clue what I'm talking about when I use that. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: That system class might be specific to after effects. You can execute a file using applescript or visual basic as well. Otherwise, what you put together looks like it should work fine. What's the problem with it?

Comment: It executes without parameters. I need to make a system call with parameters. Regardless, I wrote a batch file despite not wanting to and just got it over with

Comment: What error did you get when you used the system call?  You mention "the interpreter has no clue what I'm talking about".  Do you mean to say that ESTK returns an error that states it cannot find the system function?  What code did you use to invoke the system call?